# How to expose webapp from the private subnet to public

Tags: networking

I am working on a solution where we use some CMS and CRM (off the shelf) solutions, but use their API only and have the UI layer exposed to a unified progressive web app (PWA).

However, for time being, we need to allow some users to be able to use the CMS/CRM application directly. The user is supposed to come to the main web app (PWA) and possibly click on a link, or log in and based on the role, they get redirected to the internal web app.

Wanted to understand, if it needs exposing the internal server to the internet?

Servers are Linux VMs

Comment: Use a VPN if you wish to not expose to the Internet or else NAT or port forward via firewall rules from the public IP to whichever private IP and/or ports you need the link to send to for the access to that private network resource. You could also setup explicit rules to only allow specific public IP addresses to access that resources rather than a VPN so you'd block everything and only allow the public IP addresses of those users you allow to that resource. Just some quick thoughts based on what you are asking if I interpret that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the router/Gateway. A router is the only device that exposed to the public internet.  You should make your router as the proxy for your device.  That means you need to perform NAT (Network address translation)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Follow this link if you are using Cisco router to perform NAT

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_nat/configuration/xe-16/nat-xe-16-book/iadnat-addr-consv.html

Comment: did your problem has been solved?